# C# Table add new rows with textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got a question.
I'm making a table but I need a add page where the user can fill in a textbox, (or something else) Then press add. If this happens the table needs to be updated with the information the user added.

Could some one help me? Because I do not know how to start.

The code from the table page:

```
@model IEnumerable<DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/StyleSheet.css")
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Domeinnaam Overzicht</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("add", "CreateDomeinnaam.cshtml")


<table id="tabledomeinnamen">
<tr>
    <th>    
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActief) 
    </th>
    <th> 
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Naam)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TLD)
    </th>
    <th>    
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DatumRegistratie)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Omschrijving)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DatumOpzeg)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EigenaarID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Opmerking)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BeheerAccountID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KlantID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrarID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BetaaldVan)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BetaaldTot)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AfspraakPrijs)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActief)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Naam)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TLD)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatumRegistratie)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Omschrijving)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatumOpzeg)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EigenaarID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Opmerking)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BeheerAccountID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KlantID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrarID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BetaaldVan)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BetaaldTot)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AfspraakPrijs)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) 
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) 
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to add new rows? Or only want to edit existing rows when you click on corresponding Edit link?

Comment: @Zeshan I want to let the user add to the table. They need to click on the "Create" and then fill in textboxes (or something else) and press add. So the information gets added to the table

Comment: Let me create a jsfiddle demo for you.

Comment: @Zeshan What is jsfiddle ?:) I'm currently working with Visual Studio. Is this possible to do without javascript?

Comment: It's just online javascript demo system. Do you know Javascript? You can perform this tasks in two ways. i) via javascript and ajax ii) by submitting form to server.

Comment: If you do submit form on server then you have to refresh page. But if you do this via ajax then you don't have to refresh page.

Comment: @Zeshan I do not know Ajax or JS. But you could try to explain it with that demo program? But is there no possible way to do it without one of those?

Comment: Yes I just did answered your question. It can certainly explained without any demo program but it's lot easier to see code in action instead of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the table page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("add", "CreateDomainName", "Domain") //Second parameter is the action name, Third parameter is the controller name. If your 'list'(table) page action and 'add' action are in the same controller then this field is optional.
```

CreateDomainName action in your controller.

```
public ActionResult CreateDomainName()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateDomainName(Domeinnaam model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Your code to save
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

To generate the view of CreateDomainName action, right click on action and click on 'add view'.

View of CreateDomainName action.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <!-- Your html code -->
   <input type="submit">Add</input>
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this answer. Im kind off new to programming. the second part you have //Your code to save. What do you mean by that? And my second question is that you have at the view CreateDomeinName <input type="submit">add</input> What should be there? could you give an example?

Comment: 1. HttpPost action will be fired when you submit the form. You can retrieve the submitted data from 'model' parameter.

Comment: 1. HttpPost action will be fired when you submit the form. You can retrieve the submitted data from 'model' parameter.
Next line, I'm checking whether the model is valid or not.
If it's valid you can save it's in your database or you can do something with the submitted data.

2. You can generate 'CreateDomainName' view automatically by click on 'add view' option. (right click on CreateDomainName action name then 'add view').

Comment: I added the view. But what should be in the <input type="submit">Add</input> Can you make an example ? :)

Comment: Okay. I just wanted to show you the code snippet of generated razor view.
Actually, Html.Beginform() html helper creates 'form' tag (you can check it from chrome dev tool (F12)) and 
<input type="submit" value="add">
When you click on 'add' (submit button) form get submitted to the server.

Comment: Okay that is clear. But my question was how do I add like a domainname now? What line I need to make for that, the user needs to get a textbox. Fill in like hallo.com and then press add.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you meant. You already created it now. If you navigate to '/Domain/CreateDomainName', you can add the domain name and when you click 'add' button your httpPost action getting fired. Which you can write backend code to do something with your submitted data (Save it in a database or session). Another thing you also have other fields in your model as well. If you don't require them you can remove them from your view. Or you meant how to save your data and pass it to your table page?

Comment: Yea thats what I mean.

Comment: So could you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task in two ways:

1. Using Ajax
2. By submitting form to server and refreshing the page

Here's how you can do it via ajax.

1. Add form at top or bottom of table with required fields
2. On submit of form event process form and submit via ajax
3. In success callback append tr to table with required cells.

   `$( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#newForm").submit(function(){
       //TODO: Perform ajax call to add reccord in database
       // Append row to table
       return false;
   });`

Here's a code demo you can follow to do it with Ajax. [Add new row to table on form submit](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYeOOv)

Comment: This is above my limits, I'm new to programming. Never worked with Ajax...